How to use OAuth2 with OpenAPI Generator Python client?
I'm using OpenAPI Generator (7.8.0) to generate a pydantic-v1 Python client. The swagger includes a security scheme with OAuth2 using Client Credentials flow. The server provides a /oauth2/token route to issue new tokens. It does not reply with a token refresh though.
My question is: what does configuration look like to make it fetch a new token when needed (eg. First call, after token expiration or after any auth failed responses)
More details: the client credentials request will include username and password. It also requires basic auth.

how is your OpenAPI spec defined? You need to define the security scheme as being a client_credentials oauth flow
That said... it looks like the generator your using does't have support for Oauth2 client credentials
Disclaimer that I work for the company, but Speakeasy generates a pydantic-based client, and does have support for OAuth2. You can maintain one SDK free. I would give it a look.
